# Import data into new Storage Account Azure Resource Manager

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am creating an ARM template to deploy a handful of apps, databases and storage accounts. I am able to create a new SQL Database from a .bacpac file that sits in a storage account, and that allows me to populate data into the db on deployment. I was wondering if there is something similar for Storage Accounts. Say I want to create a new instance of an environment, but I want to load it with Storage Account Data from Production. Currently, I have a PowerShell script that gets the name and key for the source and destination storage account, and I then call AZCopy to move the data that way. Is there a preferred approach to doing this task using ARM? Is there anything in the Pipeline to allow importing data from an existing Storage Account?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Azure Data Factory with a copy activity from blob to blob? it can be created by the deployment template.

Comment: That is an interesting thought... How would you go about doing it?

Comment: You can create a Data factory account and pipeline in your template. Use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-data-factory-blob-to-sql) as a reference, though it copies from blob to sql, but it is pretty much the same. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-data-movement-activities/) is an overview on copy activity in ADF. Your pipeline will work only once - for the copy during the setup.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, please mark this as answered. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ARM doesn't have any data- or file-copying routines built-in, as it's focused on infrastructure buildout coordination. You could certainly use ARM to kick off a custom script in a VM, or some other mechanism that starts your AzCopy procedure running.

Comment: But it has Sql Import, so I was wondering if they plan to add it.

Comment: The product teams won't (at least *shouldn't*) discuss roadmap here. That said: SQL Database and Storage are completely different services, where SQL Database has native import ability and Storage doesn't.

Comment: Yes, David is right. Your current solution using AzCopy looks good and ARM doesn't support importing for Azure Storage. :)